# Uploading data with multer - image is an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, multer

I want to send product data including an image to the database. I am using multer and get the error:

> Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

I have seen that this error is very common and have tried the suggestions that are made on stack overflow without success. What makes me suspicious is, when I log the req.body, the correct data is displayed, but image is an empty object. I also logged the whole thing in my http-request, there image is a file and prototype array.

multer storage:

```
import { Request } from "express";
import multer, { FileFilterCallback } from "multer";
import path from 'path'
const maxSize = 100 * 1024 *1024;
type DestinationCallback = (error: Error | null, destination: string) => void
type FileNameCallback = (error: Error | null, filename: string) => void

 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination:(req:Request,file:Express.Multer.File, callback:DestinationCallback)=>{
            callback(null, path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'admin/public/uploads'));
        },
    
        filename: (req:Request, file:Express.Multer.File, callback:FileNameCallback)=>{
            callback(null, Date.now()+ "--"+ path.extname(file.originalname))
        },    
    })

const upload = multer({
    storage:storage,
    fileFilter:(req:Request,file:Express.Multer.File,callback:FileFilterCallback)=>{
        if(
            file.mimetype == "image/png"||
            file.mimetype == "image/jpg" ||
            file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" ||
            file.mimetype == "video/mp4"
        ){
            callback(null, true);
        } else{
            callback(null,false)
            return callback(new Error("Only .png, .jpg, .jpeg, .mp3, .mp4 allowed"))
        }
    },
    limits:{fileSize: maxSize}
});

export default upload
```

;

```
My route: 

productsRouter.post('/', upload.single('image'), verifyTokenAndAdmin, async (req:Request, res:Response)=>{
    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.body);
    try{
        const uploadResult = cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file!.path,{
            upload_preset: "webshop_ts_mern",
            resource_type: "auto",
        })
        const newProducts = new Products({
            cloudinary_id: uploadResult.public_id,
            title: req.body.title,
            producer: req.body.producer,
            categories: req.body.categories,
            desc: req.body.desc,
            price: req.body.price,
            currency:req.body.currency,
            colors:req.body.colors,
            sizes: req.body.sizes,
            inStock: req.body.inStock,
            image: uploadResult.secure_url,

        })
        const savedproducts = await newProducts.save();
        res.status(200).json(savedproducts);
    } catch(error){
        res.status(403)
        console.log(error);
        throw new Error("Action failed");
    }
});
```

Add my code from frontend.
Input with name="image":

```
<FormGroup>
            <label htmlFor='image'>Picture</label>
            <input type="file" name='image' id='image' onChange={handleFileChange} style={{marginBottom:"5px"}}/>
      {preview && <img src={preview} alt="Preview" width="300" height="200"/>}
        </FormGroup>
```

handleFileChange:

```
const [fileData, setFileData] = useState<FileData>({ image: null });
    const [preview, setPreview] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const handleFileChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const files = e.currentTarget.files;
        if (!files) {
          return;
        }
        const file = files[0]
        setFileData({image:file})
        updatePreview(files[0]);
      };
```

Formdata(image is the last entry, all entries are logged correctly):

```
  const onSubmit=(e:React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
      const productData = new FormData();
      productData.append("title", formdata.title);
      productData.append("producer", formdata.producer);
      productData.append("categories", JSON.stringify(formdata.categories));
      productData.append("desc", formdata.desc);
      productData.append("price", formdata.price);
      productData.append("colors", JSON.stringify(formdata.colors));
      productData.append("sizes", JSON.stringify(formdata.sizes));
      productData.append("inStock", formdata.inStock);
      productData.append('image', fileData.image!)
      for(let value of productData){
        console.log(value);
      }
      dispatch(createProduct(productData));
    }
```

The log of fileData.image before dispatch:

```
> (2) ['image', File] 0 :  "image" 1 :  File {name: 'golf.jpg',
> lastModified: 1643720187661, lastModifiedDate: Tue Feb 01 2022
> 13:56:27 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit), webkitRelativePath:
> '', size: 18769, …} length :  2 [[Prototype]] :  Array(0)
```

The log in my Route:

```
undefined
[0] {
[0]   title: 'Golfshoes',
[0]   producer: 'Nike',
[0]   categories: '"Sportshoes"',
[0]   desc: 'Lorem Ipsum',
[0]   price: '89',
[0]   colors: '"white, black"',
[0]   sizes: '"45, 47, 49"',
[0]   inStock: 'true',
[0]   image: {}
[0] }
```

Comment: Can you add your code that sends the image from the frontend?

Comment: @NeNaD Thanks for response. I added the frontend.

Comment: Can you try to log `fileData.image` before sending calling `dispatch()`. Maybe the property is not set properly.

Comment: What content-type header are you using when sending the form data to your server?

Comment: @morganney 'Content-Type':"application/json"

Comment: It needs to be `multipart/form-data` to work correctly. That's most likely your problem.

Comment: Whatever `dispatch(createProduct(productData));` is doing it should not explicitly set the content type header. If you are using `fetch` just send the request and the right content type will be sent automagically.

Comment: Nope, when I use this, it shows nothing, react is always application/json.

Comment: If you are certain of that then good luck, but I think you're wrong.

Comment: Did you see the comment from the multer README yet? The one that says **NOTE: Multer will not process any form which is not multipart (multipart/form-data).**?

Comment: @morganney Moment please, I try it, perhaps you are right. But I asked for that a while before and it was told me, that react is always a application/json.

Comment: @morganney You are right. Multer place it in the right folder. The reason that I see nothing is a cloudinary error: Products validation failed: image: Path `image` is required., cloudinary_id: Path `cloudinary_id` is required. In the log of req.file is the right path but cloudinary not get req.file.path